# C# command line execute commands belongs to another executable

Tags: c#, command-line, sftp

Below is the code where I'm trying to run one command with argument. (Call Tectia SFTP client profile & upload file)

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/c sftpg3 {profile}";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = cmd.StandardInput){
                    if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                        sw.WriteLine($"/c sput {filename} {output}");
         }
```

After the process started, it logins into the into the SFTP and stucked. It won't input the next command as it deemed as another program.

Would like to ask how does it execute the next command after login? I tried Calling CMD with && concatenating and it won't works too. We can only use SFTP via command line as client requested.

Comment: Don't you need to redirect the standard input like so `cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;` in order to use it ?

Comment: It was removed temporary when I was testing with other methods. Added it back. Still won't work even with those options available.

Comment: does that application have the ability to pass in a file parameter as a script so you don't have to try to redirect standard input?

Comment: Unfortunately no. We have to login first before upload the file.

Comment: Why not use a normal SFTP library instead of trying to tame an external command line program?

Comment: Because Tectia SFTP client can create profile with different type of credentials, our app just to read the profile and upload the file.

Comment: [MSDN sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) works i just tried it.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 You were right by the way (see my answer).  This application does indeed take an argument to read from a file, or from stdin.  I simply googled the application for this guy. :(

Comment: awesome...the MS OOTB ftp client has this...so i had assumed most of them would have something like that

Comment: somehow it's not that straight forward, using -B - command won't work directly. It won't read the stdin input on IIS WebAPI. I have to attach a batch file in order to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Launch `sftpg3` with the `-B -` option to read from standard input.
- Launch `sftpg3` with the `-B <filename>` option to read from a batch
  file of commands.

More details of command line arguments is available in [the documentation.](https://www.ssh.com/manuals/client-user/63/sftpg3.html)

Also, I don't think you want to write `/c` the second time around.  `/c` is just something passed to `cmd.exe`.  On that note, why are you calling `cmd.exe` instead of the binary directly?